# Kotlin properties in a package relocated with Shadow do not work

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp, shadowjar

I'm trying to relocate a package (OkHttp 4, to be specific) with [Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow), with the following Gradle config:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName.set('my_archive')
    archiveClassifier.set(null)
    version = null

    relocate 'okhttp3', 'my.prefix.okhttp3'
    relocate 'okio', 'my.prefix.okio'
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1") {
        exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module: "kotlin-stdlib"
    }
}
```

(I've omitted the `buildscript` part, the important bit there is that the version of Shadow used is `5.1.0`. Package prefixes etc have also been changed)

This worked before, with OkHttp 3.12.0 and earlier, which was purely Java. Now that OkHttp 4 is written in Kotlin, I'm having trouble using properties, in Kotlin code specifically. When used from Java, the relocated OkHttp works just fine. But accessing properties in Kotlin, like this:

```
val cache = httpClient.cache
```

... results in an exception:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getCache()Lmy/prefix/okhttp3/Cache; in class Lmy/prefix/okhttp3/OkHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'my.prefix.okhttp3.OkHttpClient' appears in /data/app/redacted.redacted-0yalPGR5aw0RSY2Zdxnq7Q==/base.apk)`

As you can see, the app is an Android app, in case that matters.

Any ideas what could be wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but makes things work at least somewhat. Instead of excluding the embedded Kotlin stdlib entirely, let it be and also relocate it. It's easiest by relocating *everything* to the same prefix, by adding this to `build.gradle`:

```
task relocateShadowJar(type: ConfigureShadowRelocation) {
    target = tasks.shadowJar
    prefix = "my.prefix"

}

tasks.shadowJar.dependsOn tasks.relocateShadowJar
```

You may also need to exclude some Kotlin `META-INF` bits in the `shadowJar` task.

The problem (at least for me) with this approach is that while everything more or less works, you now likely have the Kotlin stdlib twice in your app: your prefixed version and the one you use normally. Also, property syntax doesn't work. So as in the example in the question,

```
val cache = httpClient.cache
```

actually becomes

```
val cache = httpClient.cache()
```

... which isn't great.

Another problem for me now is that in Android Studio, everything in the resulting `jar` shows as red in the code editor, i.e. Android Studio doesn't see what's in the `jar`. Everything compiles just fine, it's just that editing code itself is a pain, since you don't get any code completion and Android Studio sometimes messes with your imports. (since it obviously thinks that these imports are invalid)

Answer (score 0):

We experience something similar in a non-android project.
The package-level "things" (an extension function in our case) are in fact static on a compiler-generated class (in our case its called ExtensionKt.class)

I have no problem accessing that class from Java or Scala code. 
In Kotlin code however the compiler does not let me to access the `ExtensionKt` class and the package relocating by the shadow Jar somehow breaks the original syntax so it is not possible to access it via the package name anymore. As a temporary workaround we access the package scoped things from Java:

So instead this Kotlin code:

```
import my.package.name.niceExtensionFunction

...

val x = SomeClass()
val y = x.niceExtensionFunction()
```

We do this in Java:

```
import my.package.name.ExtensionKt;

...

SomeClass x = new SomeClass;
Object y = ExtensionKt.niceExtensionFunction(x)
```